# Does lsi1068e offer better performance than ich10r?

Tags: raid

I have a z800 workstation with these 2 controllers. Is there a performance benefit from moving my raid10 to the LSI from the ich10r?

I have 4 Western Digital Caviar Black 1TB drives.

Comment: How would you define "performance" in this case?

Comment: faster reads / writes , or a significant cpu overhead reduction?

Comment: Ive heard that the intel is not true HW raid and uses cpu more - i guess this is why I ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It does. The Intel is a [*fake* RAID controller](http://www.servethehome.com/difference-hardware-raid-hbas-software-raid/).

Comment: thanks. However after more digging the lsi may notbe hw raid either. Agh!

Comment: It's a solid SAS HBA/controller chipset.